# process.h on Win CE

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I am working to compile some code to WinCE from Win32. It seems that process.h is not in the SDK. What can I use to replace the mutex and thread functions?

Answer (score 2):

If think the functions you are looking for may be just in winbase.h

Answer (score 1):

MSDN will tell you what headers you need for any particular API - for instance, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(VS.85).aspx) indicates CreateMutex should be brought in via windows.h

Answer (score 1):

[mbq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320951/process-h-on-win-ce/3320981#3320981) and [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320951/process-h-on-win-ce/3320990#3320990) are correct. Look at [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885181.aspx) for Windows CE. You can just search for your desired API using Bing or Google by writing the name of the function along with `Windows CE`, like [I did for this function](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=createmutex+windows+ce&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).
The `h` file you need is specified in the bottom of the page.
`windows.h` does include `winbase.h` under Windows CE.

Comment: What the heck did you do to that google link??
Edit: Nvm, your an Israeli. Please remember that the main userbase of SO is American.

Comment: Here is the .com version: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=createmutex+windows+ce

Comment: Please remember that SO is on voluntary base so be more polite. I see you managed to decipher the link, but still failed to mark an answer.